# iText Pdf splitting/clipping using setCropBox

Tags: split, itext, clipping

I've been using iText for some time, but I got stuck on the following problem:

I've got an existing PDF and I know that I have to split some of the pages at fixed points and save them as different files. For example, I want to take 3/4 of the first page, the remaining quarter with half of the second page and finally the other half of this page.

Since a PDF cannot be actually split at all, I'm trying to copy the whole page and set a cropBox to the portion I want to be visible to the user:

```
    String filePath = "xxx.pdf";

    Document document = new Document();
    Document docCopy = new Document();

    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("lastPdf.pdf"));
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filePath);
    PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(docCopy, new FileOutputStream("auxFile.pdf"));

    Rectangle crop = new Rectangle(0, 0, 300, 300);
    writer.setCropBoxSize(crop);

    document.open();
    docCopy.open();

    PdfContentByte content = writer.getDirectContent();
    PdfTemplate template = copy.getImportedPage(reader, 1);

    content.addTemplate(template, 0, 0);

    docCopy.close();
    document.close();
```

which creates an entirely empty PDF...

Comment: You're mixing `PdfWriter` and `PdfCopy` in a way that it's hard to correct your code. Did you read http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf ? Did you try the example shown in listing 6.10? Do you understand the concept?

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem. I was trying to solve it as described in listing 5.17 and setting the template as a whole page in the existing document; and I was using both PdfWriter and PdfCopy because I forgot the writer can also import pages.